# What is a teaching prep in terms of teaching load?

Tags: teaching, working-time

I am new to this job search thing, and I keep seeing the teaching load description along with something called "preps," what is this?

For reference, I am a Ph.D. student in mathematics in the U.S. looking for mostly teaching positions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A "prep" is an individual different course you are teaching.  If you are teaching 2 different sections of the same course the same semester, that counts as only 1 "prep" but counts twice towards your "teaching load".

Given not-too-large class sizes, teaching 4 courses with only 2 preps might be less work than teaching 3 courses with 3 preps, since presumably you don't have to prepare twice to teach the same class twice.

Comment: Grading--if you have to do it yourself--scales with the number of students, which generally means with the number of sections so extra section aren't really easy. But they certainly aren't as hard as teaching a distinct course.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I couldn't find this defined anywhere, and had a lot of trouble figuring out what it meant from the context.