# What term is used to refer to how teachers are allocated for each course?

Tags: teaching, terminology

A question about terminology here...

When creating schedules or timetables for our school, the first thing we do is to allocate a teacher for each course that is to be given. Example:

- John will be teaching...

  - ...Math 1 for student group A
  - ...Math 1 for student group B
- Mary will be teaching...

  - ...Physics 3 for student group B
  - ...Social Studies 2 for student group C
- ...and so on

In my native language we have an established and well known term for this, which translates directly to "service distribution" where our word for "service" is closely related to "employment".

**My question:** Is there any established terminology for this type of teacher ↔ course assignment in English? If not, what would you say is a good term?

My candidates (but I'd love to hear other suggestions):

- Teacher allocation
- Teacher deployment
- Teacher-course allocation
- Teacher-course assignment

Answer (score 30, accepted):

At University of Michigan and University of Washington, where I've taught, these were called simply *"teaching assignments"*.  If a given class is taught to multiple groups of students, e.g., at different times or by different instructors, those are called *"sections"*.  Non-teaching assignments, e.g., serving on a committee, are called *"service assignments"*.

Answer (score 3):

The general term "scheduling" is used pretty frequently. There isn't a dedicated term in English, actually. Instead, descriptive terms are used and they vary pretty widely (US). "teacher scheduling", "instructor scheduling", "course scheduling", with various substitutions for "scheduling" possible.

An individual university will have a term of art, but it will differ if you look more broadly. And, being descriptive, those using different terms will probably understand what is intended.

And, of course, there is no one-one correspondence between the terminology/words in different languages.

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for the word "preps". In your example, John has two sections, but only one prep; Mary has two sections and two preps. See [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44822/what-is-a-teaching-prep-in-terms-of-teaching-load).

Comment: "Preps" means "preparations". But I doubt that is what the OP is after.

Answer (score -1):

Scheduling. Or maybe Timetabling. Both are succinct and clear.